# remove duplicate lines from fstab file in-place

Tags: linux, text-processing, rhel

I use the following awk command ( in my bash script )  in order to remove duplicate lines from `/etc/fstab` file
and then we copy the update fstab ( `fstab.correct` ) file to /etc/fstab

```
awk '/^#/ || "'!'"a[\$0]++' /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.correct
cp /etc/fstab.correct /etc/fstab
```

since I want to prevent the copy -   `cp /etc/fstab.correct /etc/fstab`

it will be more elegant we can use sed , or perl line liner to remove the duplicate lines insted of awk

I will appreciate to get suggestion how to remove duplicate lines from `fstab` file by `sed` or `perl` one line liner

Comment: Using `sed` seems impossible without sorting the file, which I presume you cannot consider since you are talking about `/etc/fstab`. Using `perl`, this one-liner should work well: `perl -i -ne 'print if ! $x{$_}++' /etc/stab`.

Comment: ok please post your answer , seems its good solution

Comment: if your `awk` has the `inplace` option, tha should write to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sorting the file is not an option, it is impossible, as far as I know, to remove duplicate lines using `sed`.

With `perl` though, you can use this:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if ! $x{$_}++' /etc/stab
```